# If statement returning False in While True loop (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement, printing, while-loop, break

I expected that in this If statement, the variable 'i' would increment until it eventually equals 10, and subsequently 'if 10 < 10' would return False, breaking my while loop.  But this code seems print until 10 and then get stuck in an infinite loop unless I add an else: break.  Why?

```
i=0
while True:
    if i < 10:
        i = i + 1 
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while X` repeats when `X` equals to `True` so in `while True` it's always `True`. It only breaks with `break` statement.
In your code, you only check the value inside the `while` loop with if so neither you break the while loop nor you change `True` to `False` in `while True`.

If you want to use `while`:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    print(i)
```

Or

```
i = 0
while True:
    if i < 10:
        i += 1
        print(i)
    else:
        break
```

Without `while`:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you.  This has explained my broken logic.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`while True` 
will make the loop run forever because "true" always evaluates to true. You can exit the loop with a break.

To achieve what you want to do, I would use

```
while i < 10:
    print (i)
    i++
```

Comment: Yes there is obviously a lapse in my understanding here. I would have expected:  `while True: False`  ...to have broken the while loop

Answer (score 0):

That is because there isn't anything telling you to terminate the loop. So it will continue even after the if statement isn't satisfied.

This is why it is generally not a great practice to use `while True`

You can achieve the same thing with a for loop when the break condition is built into the loop:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use while True then you can go for:

```
i=0
while True:
   i = i + 1 
   print(i)
   if i == 10:
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand a few things here, as you have set `while True` which means statement will never gets `false` so there is never end to `while loop` even if `if condition` gets fail. So the `while loop` will continue running till you interrupt.

The only way you can achieve this without break is like this,  where you have a variable which will reset the condition of `while loop` to false when `if loop` fails

```
i=0
condition = True
while condition:
    if i<10:
        i=i+1
        print(i)
    else:
        condition=False
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here might be too hard to understand for a newbie. The error is that you are telling the computer to keep adding 1 in every loop until it reaches 10, and then stop... adding. As people have already said, you need to explicitly tell it to stop looping by using `break`. And even better, skip the `while` loop and use a `for` loop instead.